# How to pass more arguments to that function?

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
function mobio_checkcode($servID, $code, $debug=0) {

$res_lines = file("http://www.mobio.bg/code/checkcode.php?servID=$servID&code=$code");

$ret = 0;
if($res_lines) {

    if(strstr("PAYBG=OK", $res_lines[0])) {
        $ret = 1;
    }else{
        if($debug)
            echo $line."\n";
    }
}else{
    if($debug)
        echo "Unable to connect to mobio.bg server.\n";
    $ret = 0;
}

return $ret;
}
```

And here how i use it:

```
if(mobio_checkcode($servID, $code, 0) == 1) {
 echo "Code is valid!!";
}


$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
$servID = 29;
$post = $_REQUEST['post'];
```

Here i have form! In this form u enter code and display is valid or no so i want to pass more $code like

```
$code1 = $_REQUEST['code1'];
$code2 = $_REQUEST['code2'];
$code3 = $_REQUEST['code3'];
```

I want to pass more variables to function how it will be done.. Please help me thank u <3

Comment: Etther call function three times, for each code. Or rewrite it.

Comment: Hm... maybe have some another way or this is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass all of variables as array like

```
$array = ['servID'=>29,'code'=>XXXX];

function checkcode($array) {
//Do stuff
$array['servID']
$array['code']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mobio_checkcode($servID, $code, $debug=0, $element1, $element2) {
```

$res_lines = file("http://www.mobio.bg/code/checkcode.php?servID=$servID&code=$code");

$ret = 0;
if($res_lines) {

```
if(strstr("PAYBG=OK", $res_lines[0])) {
    $ret = 1;
}else{
    if($debug)
        echo $line."\n";
}
```

}else{
    if($debug)
        echo "Unable to connect to mobio.bg server.\n";
    $ret = 0;
}

return $ret;

//you can pass extra elements so on.. otherwise create an array of elements and pass only array to function